# content size is updating slowly when mui drawer is open / closed

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This is a dashboard in which it has headers, statbox and a datagrid. when I open and close the drawer, except the statbox, all other contents are moving slowly to the left side.

I mean if I close the drawer, the left side is working perfectly by moving to the left, but the right side content is slowly moving to the left which is bad to see and if I open it again, the content suddenly goes out of the screen and then slowly reducing the size to fit the screen

I tried many ways like fixing the size when the state oepn is true and false and setting the transition to none , but nothing works

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
  CssBaseline,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@mui/material";
import { tokens, ColorModeContext, useMode } from "../../theme";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import DownloadOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DownloadOutlined";
import PeopleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/People"; //total
import ApartmentIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Apartment"; //check-in
import DirectionsWalkIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DirectionsWalk"; //check-out
import LocalHotelIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocalHotel"; //leave
import TimeToLeaveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TimeToLeave"; //vacation
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import TopBarMui from "../../components/TopBarMui";
import Topbar from "../../components/Topbar";
import MiniDrawer from "../../components/Drawer";
import Sidebar from "../../components/Sidebar";
import StatBox from "../../components/StatBox";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const themes = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(themes.palette.mode);

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const margin = "70px 5px 0 20px";

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);

  const [totalStudentCount, setTotalStudentCount] = useState(0);
  const [checkInCount, setCheckInCount] = useState(0);
  const [checkOutCount, setCheckOutCount] = useState(0);
  const [leaveCount, setLeaveCount] = useState(0);
  const [vacationCount, setVacationCount] = useState(0);
  const [missingCount, setMissingCount] = useState(0);
  const [dashData, setDashData] = useState();
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  
  const NavigateInfo = () => {
    navigate("/student/info");
  };


  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <MiniDrawer open={open} toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} />

          <Box className="content">
            <TopBarMui toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} />
            {/* <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} /> */}
            <Box m="80px 5px 0 20px">
              {/* HEADER */}
              <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
              >
                <Header
                  title="DASHBOARD"
                  subtitle="Welcome to your dashboard"
                />

                <Box>
                  <Button
                    sx={{
                      backgroundColor: colors.blueAccent[700],
                      color: colors.grey[100],
                      fontSize: "14px",
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      padding: "10px 20px",

                      "&:hover": {
                        color: colors.blueAccent[900], // Change the text color on hover
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    <DownloadOutlinedIcon sx={{ mr: "10px" }} />
                    Download Reports
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </Box>

              {/* Grids */}
              <Box
                display="flex"
                gridTemplateColumns="repeat(3,1fr)"
                gridAutoRows="1fr"
                gap="15px"
              >
                {/* Counts Row */}

                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                  onClick={NavigateInfo} // Add the onClick event here
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<PeopleIcon />}
                    title="Total"
                    count={totalStudentCount}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<ApartmentIcon />}
                    title="Check IN"
                    count={checkInCount}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<DirectionsWalkIcon />}
                    title="Check Out"
                    count={checkOutCount}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<LocalHotelIcon />}
                    title="Leave"
                    count={leaveCount}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<TimeToLeaveIcon />}
                    title="Vacation"
                    count={vacationCount}
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 3"
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  backgroundColor={colors.grey[300]}
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="center"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <StatBox
                    icon={<ApartmentIcon />}
                    title="Missing"
                    count={missingCount}
                  />
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            {/* Count based on dept & year */}
            <Box
              m="40px 60px 2px 20px"
              width="92.8%"
              height="45vh"
              sx={{
                "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
                  fontSize: "16px",
                  fontfamily: "serif",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  //backgroundColor: colors.blueAccent[700],
                },
              }}
            >
              <DataGrid
                rows={dashData || []}
                columns={
                  dashData
                    ? Object.keys(dashData[0])
                        .filter((columnName) => columnName !== "serial_no") // Exclude "serial_no" column
                        .map((columnName) => ({
                          field: columnName,
                          headerName: columnName,
                          flex: 1,
                        }))
                    : []
                }
                autoHeight
                getRowId={(row) => row.serial_no} // Use the "serial_no" field as the unique ID
              />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```